# How to download Minecraft for free?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I download Minecraft for free? Not online, it's a free download, how do I download it for free? I know a few games do not cost money. I tried to search for it but I couldn't find it.

Comment: The only way to legally get Minecraft is to pay for it. We don't support questions asking to get games through illegal means (i.e. for free).

Answer (score 3):

Minecraft **is not free**. It is paid software. The only 'free' full version is **illegal**.

If you mean a trial, then visit [the demo page](https://minecraft.net/en/demo/) for a free 100 minute trial.